# Vim - How can I check if the word under the cursor is a variable or not?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm writing a Vim function that generates a fmt.Println() to print out the value of the variable under the cursor (for golang)

```
function! Println()
    let wordUnderCursor = expand("<cword>")

    let fileExtension = expand('%:e')

    if fileExtension == "go"
        execute "normal! ofmt.Println(\"" . wordUnderCursor . " = \", " . wordUnderCursor . ")"
    endif

endfunction

nmap <leader>l :call Println()<CR>
```

It works, but I was just wondering, how would I go about checking if the word under cursor is a variable or not?

I have [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) installed which uses the [gopls](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls) language server under the hood.

Does anyone know how I can leverage [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) or [gopls](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls)  to find out whether or not the word under the cursor is a variable or not?

Answer (score 0):

Simply but not perfectly, you can check the whole file to see if it appears before `=` or `:=` (surrounded by space) which means it is a variable that has been assigned. Please note that those not initialized is left out.

```
" var abc, ... = 1
" abc, ... := 1
" var (
"   abc int = 1
" )

function! IsGoVarible(word)
  return search(a:word.'.* :\?= ', 'bn') != 0
endfunction

echo IsGoVarible('abc')
```